# Getting shipping and billing addresses from a guest-checkout order

Tags: shipping, customer, ee-1.12, address, billing

For orders checked out by a non-registered customer (i.e. guest), Magento doesn't create a customer. However, it does store the address information in `sales_flat_order_address`. How do you access this data? Under this table, there are columns like `firstname`, `lastname`, `address_type` (billing/shipping), etc. which are what I need.

I tried loading the order object (`sales/order`), thinking the associated table data would be available from this, but they don't seem to be. Since I can't get the `entity_id`s of `sales_flat_order_address` corresponding to an order in `sales_flat_order`, how would I get the shipping and billing address in this case? I am not able to load by the `parent_id`, which is the row ID of the main order table, either.

I can access `sales_flat_order_payment` data via `->getPayment()`, but `->getAddress(es)()` doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's say that you have the order id 10000015:
So

```
$orderId = '10000015';
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
```

Comment: I see it now in `Order.php` for the `Sales` model. Thanks!

Comment: Correction: `Sales` module is what I meant! (`Mage_Sales_Model_Order`)

Comment: @Marius I am using the above code and the log file captured is 5mb and it has all [customer_eav_attribute] ? can you guess whats the wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Get shipping details by order id

```
$order_id = 2314; //use your own order id 

$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); //load order by order id 

$shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();

 echo $shipping_address->getTelephone(); 

echo $shipping_address->getPostcode(); //use print_r($shipping_address->getData()); to get all the available elements of the object
```