# Getting name from billing address

Tags: checkout, php, customer, sales

I'm currently working in the `success.phtml` file. I need to get the name from the shipping address the user put in. I used to have code that would only grab the username of the user and would display `Guest` for a name if the user was not logged in. So I decided the name from the shipping address would most likely be the correct one to get. Here is the code I am using.

```
<?php 
$grayson_order_id = $this->getOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($grayson_order_id);
$custname = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
?>
```

But the page crashes at `$custname = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();`

I don't think it really matters but im running Magento EE 1.13

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, or I'm simply calling the wrong method.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Related question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9778/getting-shipping-and-billing-addresses-from-a-guest-checkout-order?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$this->getOrderId()` returns the increment ID (i.e. 100000456) and not the actual database ID.  You'll need to use `loadByIncrementId()` instead of `load()`:

```
<?php 
$grayson_order_id = $this->getOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($grayson_order_id);
$custname = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
?>
```

(The page was crashing at that point because `$order->getBillingAddress()` didn't return anything, and you can't call `->getName()` on a null value.)

Answer (score 1):

As Sales Order address table  `have not any field 'name' and sales Address Model`ldo not have `any Function getName()`,So Can not get `Order full name from sales Order address using getName function`

**EDIT** 
My Above Description is totally wrong ,@Colin is right.

```
$custname = $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname().' '.$order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();
```

Comment: The absence of the `name` field doesn't matter, because `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract` has a `getName()` method.

Comment: Colin  Sales Order address is not depends on customer  Mage_Customer_Model_Address, You can  check this for guest user.As i thought,My answer is not accept for down vote

Comment: `getBillingAddress()` returns a [`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Address.php#L74) instance.  That class extends [`Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php#L34), which is where the [`getName()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php#L77-98) method is provided.

Comment: You can also check the [Magento docs for `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address.html) which show this inheritance and the `getName()` method.

Comment: Thanks @ColinO'Dell,For give right point,it will give u upvote

Answer (score 1):

`$this->getOrderId()` return order increment id

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$custname = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
```

To load by order id

```
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId(); // try also $this->getRealOrderId() or $this->getLastOrderId()
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
$custname = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
```